# UIPageViewController Atualizar Conteudo e Bounce

Tags: swift

Possua uma Página em meu aplicativo que trabalha com UIPageViewController, nela eu implemento o UIPageViewControllerDataSource. Assim eu possuo uma lista de itens que são listados em varias views, o problema é que quando eu atualizo esta lista, os itens funcionam perfeitamente, consigo navegar em todos os itens, inclusive os novos. O problema é que o Bounce (bolinhas de baixo) ficam o valor antigo, ou seja, se possuía 5 paginas antes e agora 6 continua 5 bolinhas. Não achei na documentação nenhum comando que atualize essa informação. Segue abaixo parte da minha class que trata do UIPageViewControllerDataSource.

```
func loadPageView() {
    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController;
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

    let startVc = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController;
    let viewsControllers : [ContentViewController] = [startVc];

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewsControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil);

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width , self.view.frame.size.height - 70);
    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController);
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view);
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self);
}


func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ContentViewController {
    if((ExercicioDataSource.listaExercicios.count == 0) || (index >= ExercicioDataSource.listaExercicios.count)){
        return ContentViewController();
    }

    let vc : ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController;
    vc.dataContent = ExercicioDataSource.listaExercicios[index];
    vc.index = index;

    return vc;
}

// UI Page View Data Source

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let vc = viewController as! ContentViewController;
    var index = vc.index as Int;

    if(index == 0 || index == NSNotFound){
        return nil;
    }

    index -= 1;
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index);
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let vc = viewController as! ContentViewController;
    var index = vc.index as Int;
    if(index == NSNotFound){
        return nil;
    }

    index += 1;

    if(index == ExercicioDataSource.listaExercicios.count){
        return nil;
    }
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index);
}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return ExercicioDataSource.listaExercicios.count;
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Provavelmente ele não está recebendo dados automaticamente do page view controller através do delegate; portanto, sempre que adiciona uma página nova, ele não detecta as mudanças. Uma pergunta: se você deletar um VC, ele continua constando como 5 ao invés de atualizar para 4 bolinhas? Poderia postar o código inteiro incluindo viewDidLoad e variáveis definidas? De qualquer forma, tente esse método:

Antes de tudo, faça o outlet do Page Control (bolinhas) no código.

```
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
```

Agora...

1. No PageViewController:

Defina o protocolo:

```
protocol PageViewControllerDelegate: class {

    //chamado quando o número de páginas for atualizado: 
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
        didUpdatePageCount count: Int)

    //chamado quando o index for atualizado
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
        didUpdatePageIndex index: Int)

}
```

Defina uma variável conforme o novo delegate PageViewController:

```
weak var pageDelegate: PageViewControllerDelegate?
```

Adicione no viewDidLoad():

```
pageDelegate?.pageViewController(self,
            didUpdatePageCount: ExercicioDataSource.listaExercicios.count)
```

---

2. No ContentViewController:

Adicione a extensão:

```
extension ContentViewController: TutorialPageViewControllerDelegate {

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    didUpdatePageCount count: Int) {
        pageControl.numberOfPages = count
    }

    func tutorialPageViewController(tutorialPageViewController: TutorialPageViewController,
        didUpdatePageIndex index: Int) {
         index = vc.index
    }

}
```